# How do imported functions impact component rendering in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I define a function in a utils.js:

```
//utils.js

    export function formatName(name) {
      return name + '!!!'
    }
```

And in one of my components, in another file, I import and use that function:

```
//ListItem.js

    class ListItem extends PureComponent {
      
      render() {
        const {itemName} = this.props 
        const formatted = formatName(itemName)
        return (
          <div>
            {formatted}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Does using formatName have any impact on whether ListItem will re-render? As far as I understand It's not state, and not props, but I don't know if it has any unintended impact and have not been able to find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, it doesn't matter, `formatName` will not cause re-render. However, one thing to note is that, `formatName` will be trigger everytime your component is re-render, if your component re-trigger for 1000 times, `formatName` will be invoked for 1000 times